# NODEJS: req.body.InputName => undefinded

Tags: node.js, undefined, req

this my controller

```
//...
if (req.method == 'POST') {
        try {
            //..
            console.log(req.body.customerName);
}
```

I was trying to see if the req.body returned data but it returned undefined
this my route

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router()
//...
router.get('/add-bill',check_login.yeu_cau_dang_nhap, billController.addBill);
router.post('/add-bill',check_login.yeu_cau_dang_nhap, billController.addBill);
//use body-parser in app.js

var app = express();
//...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
//...
```

i tried installing "body-parser" library
but it doesn't work

Comment: Add backend code to Your question. Frontend code does not tell anything, I want to see how You attach body-parser to express app.

Comment: here is route
router.get('/add-bill',check_login.yeu_cau_dang_nhap, billController.addBill);
router.post('/add-bill',check_login.yeu_cau_dang_nhap, billController.addBill);

Comment: can you share how you use `body-parser`, and how the post request looks like?

Comment: i use in app.js
`var app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'NDASHUDHAUHD3427328guisfjsdfkjshdjhsafkjsdfkeasdasdasdfsdwe',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));`

Answer (score 1):

To parse mutlipart-form You've to install `multer`, for other body types `body-parser`

If Your form sends only text fields then change `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in form tag and no need for `multer` cause `body-parser` works perfect with non `multipart` enctype.

But if Your form has file input, then You've to use `multer`.

2 solutions:

1. simply add `multer.none()` at parent level:

```
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
//...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(multer.none());
```

2. You can add it to inner route:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');

const homeController = require('../controllers/homecontroller');
const billController = require('../controllers/lichdatcontroller');
const check_login = require('../middlewares/check_login');

const router = express.Router();

router.get(
  '/add-bill',
  check_login.yeu_cau_dang_nhap, 
  billController.addBill);


const billsDir = __dirname__ + '/../uploads/bills';
try {
  fs.mkdirSync(billsDir, { recursive: true });
}
catch (e) {}

router.post(
  '/add-bill',
  check_login.yeu_cau_dang_nhap,
  bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }), //  <-- if enctype not multipart 
  multer({ dest: billsDir }),                 //  <-- if form is multipart
  billController.addBill);

module.exports = router;
```

also, create `getBill` method in `billController` and don't use `req.method === 'POST'`  cause You're already doing by `router.post`

Comment: oh thankyou
it worked